# Email-based IRC-like software?

Tags: chat

Is there a software where people can chat individually and in a group, but without a center server, and all communication transferred via users' email?

For example, when a user talks with another user, what actually happens is that an email was sent. When a user joins a chatroom, the mechanism is that everyone else in this chatroom receives an email notifying that a new user is in.

I guess someone should have built such a software, since it requires no special servers, but makes use of the existing ones for email.

(Maybe plugins for digsby & pidgin?)

I wish it open-source and HTML & JS based (c.f. Electron), so that it is easier to be ported into various platforms.

Comment: Not sure how well it fits your bill, but did you take a look at [Der E-Mail-Messenger - Delta Chat](https://delta.chat/)? You didn't specify what OS it must run on (DeltaChat supports Android, iOS/macOS, Linux & Windows, so you should be covered concerning that) or how much it may cost (DC is free/libre & open source).

Comment: @Izzy That's exactly what I am looking for, thank you!! Will you turn it into an answer?

Comment: Glad to read! And done: answer below with a few additional details. Enjoy! \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Delta Chat](https://delta.chat/)** seems to be what you are after. It uses plain IMAP as back-end (so all that's needed is an EMail account you already have, and Delta will have its own mail folder in there).

- **but without a center server:** no central server, it works via each user's mailbox
- **all communication transferred via users' email:** exactly ;)
- **what actually happens is that an email was sent:** that's what's happening in the background – though at the front-end it looks like a chat client
- **open-source:** sources can be found [at Github](https://github.com/deltachat/)

Delta Chat is available cross-platform, with clients for Android, iOS/macOS, Linux & Windows.